# How do I set the height of a toolbar in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have this code in my applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
navController.toolbarHidden = NO;
[navController toolbar].tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[[navController toolbar] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,180.0)];
```

The first two lines definitely have an effect on the UI.  For example, if I set toolbarHidden to YES, it is certainly hidden.  However, when I try to set the frame and customize the toolbar height, no change takes place.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIToolbar`s have a fixed height. You won't be able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your own toolbar class if you need one with an adjustable height.

Answer (score 0):

if you were to create your own toolbar, you can just use the frame property of the toolbar to create it.  UINavigationController's toolbar height is not adjustable.